# $f:X\to Y$ is continuous $\iff f^{-1}(A^*) \subseteq (f^{-1}(A))^*$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Really struggling with exercise 9.10 from Sutherland's "Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces".  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $(X,t), (Y,t)$ be topological spaces, and $f: X \to Y$ be a function. Prove that $f\text{ is continuous} \iff f^{-1}(A^*) \subseteq (f^{-1}(A))^*$

(where A* represents the interior of A)

Many thanks

Comment: You know that $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimages of open sets are always open?

Comment: Yes. I had a feeling this was connected somehow but I just can't fill in the blanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is continuous, so that inverse images of open sets are open.

Let $A \subset Y$. Then $A^\ast$ is open, so $f^{-1}[A^\ast]$ is open and as $A^\ast \subseteq A$, we know that $f^{-1}[A^\ast] \subseteq f^{-1}[A]$. So as the interior of a set is the *largest* open subset of a set...

On the other hand, if the condition on the right is met, let $O \subseteq Y$ be open, so $O = O^\ast$.
We know that $f^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[O^\ast] \subseteq (f^{-1}[O])^\ast \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$, so ...

Comment: Thanks so much for the speedy reply. The left way makes perfect sense to me now, though I'm slightly confused by the other direction.

I assume here O is taking the place of A previously? How can we assume O to be open? I did forget to mention in the question this is for any subset A of Y. Regardless I also don't quite yet see the connection to continuity from where you leave it?

Comment: To show continuity we need to show that for $O$ open, $f^{-1}[O]$ is open too, so $f^{-1}[O]$ should be equal to its interior. And yes, I use $O$ for $A$, the variable name does not matter.

Comment: And the penny drops... Thank you so much for all your help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: I guess "as $A \subset A^\ast$, we know that $f^{-1}[A^\ast] \subseteq f^{-1}[A]$"" is a typo and it should be "as $A^\ast \subset A$", right? (This was pointed out in [General Topology chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/15201/2021/2/6).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I’ve edited it accordingly.