# Continuity in terms of interior of preimage and preimage of interior

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $f$ be a map between metrix spaces $X,Y$. In order to prove:

$f$ is continuous $\iff$ $f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int} Y)\subset \operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}(Y))$

I did:
$\rightarrow$
Suppose $x\in f^{-1}(\operatorname{Int} Y)$, then $f(x)\in \operatorname{Int}(Y)$. Since $f(x)\in \operatorname{Int}( Y)$, by definition of the interior set, there is an open ball such that $B(f(x), \epsilon)\subset Y$. Since $f$ is continuous, there is $\delta$ such that:

$$f(B(x,\delta))\subset B(f(x),\epsilon)\subset Y$$

that is, $B(x,\delta)\subset f^{-1}(Y)$, that is, $x\in \operatorname{Int}(f^{-1}(Y))$

$\leftarrow$
Now how to return using a similar argument?

Comment: What's $Y$?????

Comment: @ZacharySelk f is more than likely a map from $X$ to $Y$ where each are topological spaces. It seems as though they are also metric spaces. This is where I see how the question what is Y??? may arise, now I'm stumped too.

Comment: Are $X,Y$ metric spaces??

Comment: See also: [$f:X\to Y$ is continuous $\iff f^{-1}(A^*) \subseteq (f^{-1}(A))^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038809).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of equivalent continuity criteria.

[image]
[image]

Ryszard Engelking,*General Topology,* 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

Comment: i have been going through a self study of equivalent definitions of continuity and every time i thought i have seen them all, another one pops up