# When are continuous functions defined on open sets vs closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was given the following theorem as part of homework:
A mapping $f:(X,d)\rightarrow(Y,\rho)$ is continuous iff either of the following is satisfied: For each set $U$ that is open in $Y$, $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$; for each set $K$ that is closed in $Y$, $f^{-1}[K]$ is closed in $\mathbb{X}$.
I know you can prove the iff for each one of them, but how would you prove the "either" clause?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. A map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff for each set $U$ that is open in $Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ iff for each set $K$ that is closed in $Y$, $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed in $\mathbb{X}$.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to see how to construct the string of implications.

Comment: Any of these strings of implications should be easily provable. Also 
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2009608/71850) my answer contains a lot of equivalent continuity 
criteria for maps between topological spaces and implications between them.